# how to call just one argument in the secondary function in python

Tags: python, class, methods

i have the following code:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name,val):
     self.name = name
     self.val = val
class B(A):
  super(A)__init__ // here i want to have just a variable self.name. that means val=0
  def outputName(self):
      print(f"name = {self.name}")
class C(A):
  super(A)__init__ // here i want to habe just a variable self.val. that means name = 0
  def outputVal(self):
      print(f"val= {self.val}")

n = B('martin')
v = C(25)
outputName(n)
outputVal(v)
```

My Question: How can i specify that i just want name in class B in val in class C?
an another solution that i know is e.g. n=B('Martin',0) and v =C(0,25) but i think it is nonesense
Any idea how i can right it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you just need to feed a specific variable to `super()`. Minor notes: since you have a single inheritance, you don't need to specify which class you're instantiating when calling `super()`. Also, don't forget the "dot" in `super().__init__()` and, most importantly, don't forget to define `__init__()` in subclasses:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name, val):
     self.name = name
     self.val = val

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name, val=None) # Only initialise name variable of the base class
    def outputName(self):
        print(f"name = {self.name}")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__(name=None, val=val) # Same here but with val instead.
    def outputVal(self):
        print(f"val= {self.val}")
```

Or, alternatively, as Tim has suggested you can make class A have default values in init:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val=None, name=None):
```

Comment: That won't work because A.__init__ has two required parameters.  You'd need `class A:` / `def __init__(self, name=0, val=0):`

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad.